# Superglobals and htmlentities

Tags: php, html-entities, superglobals

I was reading about Superglobals and security. As a “rule”, I use **htmlentities()** for all the inputs and similar and for

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
$_POST['thename'];
$_GET['thename'];
```

But since I am a novice **I don´t know if I have to use it with some or all the other superglobals.** I don´t know about security and maybe, someone can do “something” to put (or change) malicious code.

**Do I have to use it just for those ones? Or are others to consider?**

Thanks a lot.

I´m asking to learn in the good way.

Comment: extremely broad, it depends entirely what you are going to do with the value from a super-global. there is no magic function you would should run on all of them (or php would do that for you) Automatically using `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` is a bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `htmlentities()`, use `htmlspecialchars()`.

And use that function whenever you have some plain text that should be inserted into HTML. This is without exception - always do it. It has nothing to do with security in the first place, it is simply the way to achieve correct text output.

Other functions you should be using: `urlencode()` or `rawurlencode()`.

Comment: `if(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])=="http://google.com"){//i see problems}; `this advise is a little overly general for me and full ofpitfalls

Comment: What kind of problems do you see in your simple example? I wouldn't use `htmlspecialchars()` at all there, and use strict `===` comparison. It is correct, the question has a vast answer space because it does not specify anything at all - I tried to give a specific answer for a defined use case (embedding strings in HTML) with an unexpected function call and some more. Maybe I missed the target.